# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [224, 8385]

Tags: image-processing, image-classification

File "C:\Users\SONY\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 262, in check_consistent_length
raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [224, 8385]

while running  this line:
RF_model.fit(X_for_RF, y_train)

I want to fix that error